# call two promises in the .then() clause in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, resolve

I have one promise which when it resolves, it will return "ResponseA" and in the .then() clause it is suppose to call two other promise and when they fulfill, it should print out the values(tgResponse.length and igResponse.length). But the problem is, it is always printing the value of last promise and skipping the first one which is console.log('igResponse', igResponse.length);
Why this happens? and how can I make sure that it runs igApiPromise and tgApiPromise in parallel and prints the value for both of them. Thanks a lot for your help.

Here is my code:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            /// do some stuff
                    resolve(responseA)
                }
            });
        }).then(ResponseA => {
            console.log(ResponseA.Values);
            igApiPromise(ResponseA.Values.token).then(igResponse => {
                console.log('igResponse', igResponse.length);
            });
            tgApiPromise(ResponseA.Values).then(tgResponse => {
                console.log('tgResponse', tgResponse.length);
            });  
         });

        let igApiPromise = token => {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                console.log('lotfan');
                xhttp.open("GET", "/api/igconfig", true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
                xhttp.onload = function () {
                    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300 && this.readyState == 4) {
                        resolve(xhttp.response);
                    } else {
                        reject({
                            status: this.status,
                            statusText: xhttp.statusText
                        });
                    }
                };
                xhttp.onerror = function () {
                    reject({
                        status: this.status,
                        statusText: xhttp.statusText
                    });
                };
                xhttp.send();
            });
        }

        let tgApiPromise = token => {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                xhttp.open("GET", "/api/tgApidata", true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
                xhttp.onload = function () {
                    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300 && this.readyState == 4) {
                        resolve(xhttp.response);
                    } else {
                        reject({
                            status: this.status,
                            statusText: xhttp.statusText
                        });
                    }
                };
                xhttp.onerror = function () {
                    reject({
                        status: this.status,
                        statusText: xhttp.statusText
                    });
                };
                xhttp.send();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Read up on `Promise.all` in the mdn docs. It accepts an array of promises and waits for all promises to resolve until continuing.

Comment: tried that and still the last one resolve only :(, really stuck here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Promise.all` should look something like this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(responseA)
    }
  });
}).then(ResponseA => {
  const igPromise = igApiPromise(ResponseA.Values.token)
  const tgPromise = tgApiPromise(ResponseA.Values)
  return Promise.all([igPromise, tgPromise])
}).then(responses => {
  const igResponse = responses[0]
  const tgResponse = responses[1]
  console.log('igResponse', igResponse.length)
  console.log('tgResponse', tgResponse.length)
})
```

Also, if you put your functions `igApiPromise` and `tgApiPromise` below the place you're using it, don't do variable assignment. Use the `function` syntax.

```
function igApiPromise(token) {
}
```

I'm surprised you original code didn't throw an error.

edit: Something is wrong with your api calls then. This barebones example with `Promise.all` works perfectly fine. it finished both in 6 seconds, as expected.

```js
function runProm() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('1000'), 2000)
  }).then(ResponseA => {
    const igPromise = igApiPromise(ResponseA)
    const tgPromise = tgApiPromise(ResponseA)
    return Promise.all([igPromise, tgPromise])
  }).then(responses => {
    const igResponse = responses[0]
    const tgResponse = responses[1]
    console.log('igResponse', igResponse)
    console.log('tgResponse', tgResponse)
  })
}

function igApiPromise(token) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('eyegApiPromise' + token), 4000)
  })
};

function tgApiPromise(token){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('teegApiPromise' + token), 40)
  })
}

runProm()
```

edit2:

Did you declare `xhttp` in each respective function? This needs to be inside both .

```
let igApiPromise = token => {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I did the change as you suggested but now it doesn't print anything

Comment: @AlreadyLost Updated. Something is wrong with your api calls then.

Comment: when I have only one of the promises, it works. I mean if I do Promise.all([igPromise]) only or Promise.all([tgPromise]) only it works, but when I put both it doesn't work :(

Comment: So... did you intentionally omit your `xhttp` assignment in each function? If you don't declare it inside each function it's going to grab it from the scope above it. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but it's possible that one is overwriting the other.

Comment: yes that was the issue and it wasn't intentional. thank you so much for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer it totally correct regarding the use of `Promise.all`, you should use that.

> It is always printing the value of last promise and skipping the first one. Why this happens?

I guess your actual problem is that you have a global `xhttp` variable with a single `XMLHttpRequest` instance, which is used by both your functions. They cannot both run in parallel because the last call is overwriting the handlers that the former calls did install.

Create a new one for every function call, right before using it.

```
function …ApiPromise(token) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         xhttp.open("GET", …);
         …
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, yes, yes, the issue was that. Thank youvery much both Bergi and Andrew <3

Answer (score -1):

You can try using ES7's async await feature.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function